# Java regex for inserting text between braces

Tags: java, regex, string, braces

I have a String

```
a = "stringWithBraces()"
```

I want to create the following string

```
"stringWithBraces(text)"
```

How do I achieve this using regex?

I tried this :

```
a.replaceAll("\\(.+?\\)", "text");
```

But get this :

```
stringWithBraces()
```

Comment: `+` must match at least once, you need to use `*`.

Comment: do you mean you wanna achieve something like: String first = "(abc)"; String myVariable = "def"; to become String first = "abc(def)"?

Comment: Why not use a literal replacement? `.replace("()", "(" + text + ")")`? Note there is nothing wrong with the `"(" + text + ")"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookaheads and do something like this:

```
(?<=\().*?(?=\))
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aFu2JF/1)

Thus doing this:

```
String a = "stringWithBraces()";
a = a.replaceAll("(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))", Matcher.quoteReplacement("text"));

System.out.println(a);
```

Outputs:

```
stringWithBraces(text)
```

Note that in relation to `replaceAll()` then the `replacement` string has some special character. So you should most likely use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) in order to escape those and be safe.

Comment: Note that the `"text"` is in fact a variable. And a string variable may contain special chars that are treated specifically in a replacement pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks forgot about that. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
a = a.replaceAll("\\((.*?)\\)", "(text)");
```

You have to replace every thing between parenthesis with `(text)`

Comment: hmm I was trying to avoid "(" + variable + ")"

Comment: what did you mean @user_mda ?

Comment: 'text'  in my question is a variable. So I didnt want to append "(" + variable + ")" but just replace what is between the braces with the variable

Comment: why you want to avoid this solution @user_mda ?

Answer (score 0):

`+` requires at least one char, the `?` added here means the shortest match, so "...(.)...(.)..." would not continue to find ".)...(.".

```
a.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "(text)");
```

You might have intended `replaceFirst`; though I think not.

You might also let the dot `.` match new line chars, for mult-line matches,
using the DOT_ALL option `(?s)`:

```
a.replaceAll("(?s)\\(.*?\\)", "(text)");
```